# Fuse help F 4.0 A

Tags: pcb, fuses

I hoped to get help identifying a fuse in my underfloor heating wiring centre, the spec on the PCB is "F 4.0 A" but the actual fuse has written on it "T 2.5A H250V P". I think it's a 2.5A fast blow fuse - would it be an issue using a 3.15A fuse instead? It is 20mm x 5mm and white in colour (not clear). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the PCB reads is **F**ast acting 4 A fuse, the blown fuse you removed is a **T**ime delayed 2.5 A fuse.

You should replace the fuse with the recommended type from the PCB.

Answer (score 1):

If specs says "F 4.0 A" ideally should use a 4 amp fuse. Probably a fuse rated less works, but not for a long term. In other case, using a fuse rated higher, your circuit risk being damaged.

The fuse you mentioned in white color, means it is a ceramic fuse. Normally we know the glass fuse. Ceramic fuse have better level of thermal and arc protection.

You can check this  [URL](https://forum.digikey.com/t/glass-vs-ceramic-fuses-whats-the-difference/8475) with interesting information about fuses.

Joel.

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much for your help